# Why is this array considered to be an object, and how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, recursion

Good morning everyone!
I have a little issue. I want to check for a field in the DB and I want to store it into a variable. To do so I did this:

```
async function buildUsername(value) {
    const { db } = await connectToDatabase(URI, DATABASE);
    let obj = await db.collection(COLLECTION).find({username: value}).toArray()
    //here I want to do something like: let username = obj.username
    return typeof obj
}
```

This returns me ***object***.

If I log **obj** it outputs a structure like the following:

```
[
    {
        name: "tom"
        username: "tomhopkins"
        //etc...

    }
]
```

I want to access the username and store it into a variable. If I do: `username = obj[0].username` it doesn't work because it says **obj** is not an array, it is an object.

I have to say that I can't do it with callbacks because I need to return a username that is not already stored in the DB.

*For example*: if there is stored a document with username "tomhanks" and there is another person with the same name, I can't register the same username. I call the function username, add a suffix (an integer at the end) and check again if there is another one.if there is not then I return it, otherwise i call the function recursively with the `username + suffix` and so on.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `typeof new Array()` is also "object" so that value isn't really very helpful. Based on what you show being logged it doesn't make sense that `obj[0].username` isn't working. What does `console.log(Array.isArray(obj))` return?

Comment: Also should await before using `toArray()`  Try wrapping the await in `()` ... `let obj = (await db.collection(COLLECTION).find({username: value})).toArray()`

Comment: @charlietfl first of all thank you for answering. if I log console.log(Array.isArray(obj)) it says "false" and obj[o].username undefined

Comment: @charlietfl solved it with findOne(). it doesn't change the logic. Thank you again!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.find() method return an array , try to use .findOne() : it returns an object :

```
let obj = await db.collection(COLLECTION).findOne({username: value})
// here you can use obj.username
```